# Peg Thing example in Clojure for the brave and true:will there be a stack overflow problem?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to learn Clojure by following the book "Clojure for the Brave and True". In chapter five there is an example program "Peg Thing". The full source code for the problem can be found at [github](https://github.com/flyingmachine/pegthing).

My question is, it looks like the functions are calling each other and the stack is growing with every move, until you exit the game. Am I correct? So, potentially if we make a robot play this game for millions of rounds, at some point we will get a stack overflow. `prompt-move` calls itself, but without calling `recur`. And in a successful move, `game-over` will be called, and if the user wants to play more, there will be more stacks on top of the current stack frame. Am I getting it wrong, or is this implemented in a simplistic way as a demo and the implementer doesn't care about possibility of a million game plays?

Comment: You're right -- there are ways in Clojure to avoid an ever-growing stack (beyond loop/recur, see also [`trampoline`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/trampoline)), but reviewing the code, it doesn't appear to use them. That said, note that we ask that Stack Overflow questions be **self-contained**; a question that can't be answered (or whose answer can't be understood and helpful to others) without referring to a link is unacceptable.

Comment: This is a great question to ask on the  [Clojurian Slack](http://clojurians.net/) .

Comment: I must admit I was a bit disappointed by this sample code. After reading earlier in the chapter "Of course, your program has to have some side effects...Otherwise, there’d be no point in running it".  I thought "aha - here's where they will show us how to mutate state in a clojure-esque way", only to find it just relies on recursing deeper and deeper with every user interaction, which isn't a sensible strategy in the real world.